# Socket waiting indefinitely during GLORP + Postgres insert to DB

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

While inserting multiple records to DB ,i find that at times the thread waits indefinitely at `Socket -> waitForDataIfClosed:` where the `readSemaphore` is asked to wait. I am not too much into sockets, i would appreciate if any Pharo gurus can take a look at it.

I have objects derived from `PersistentObject` , and its session will always return a single instance of `GlorpSession`. A collection of such objects are itratively sent messages `bePersistent` and `commitUnitOfWork`.

```
    myPersistantObjectCollection do:[:each | each bePersistent;
                                           commitUnitOfWork.]
```

Would appreciate any sort of comments.
Thanks.

Comment: Which DatabaseDriver are you using? PostgresV2?